# New Year Algorithm 2019

Tags: suporte

A lot of thanks to [@Homer Simpson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/77665/homer-simpson) for the translation!

---

Ano Novo e [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo) sempre se juntam: nós convidamos você a participar do concurso de Ano Novo para as melhores perguntas e respostas na tag de [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo)!

As regras são bem simples: você precisa fazer perguntas com a tag do [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo) e respondê-las.

#### Mais detalhes

O concurso envolve todas as perguntas feitas de 1º de janeiro a 31 de janeiro de 2019 com a tag [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo), bem como as respostas dadas para o mesmo período às perguntas com a tag [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo)<sup>*</sup>.

*<sub>Examinarei o tempo de criação de uma resposta, o que significa que, se uma resposta for postada em uma pergunta que foi feita antes do término do período do concurso, a resposta também será levada em conta ao calcular os resultados.</sub>

#### Vencedores

Os vencedores serão:

1. Autor de uma pergunta com a maior pontuação.
2. Autor de uma resposta com a maior pontuação.
3. Autor de uma resposta à sua própria pergunta, se a resposta obtiver uma pontuação maior do que qualquer outra resposta à pergunta.
4. Autor de uma resposta aceita com a maior pontuação.
5. Autor de uma pergunta que obtenha mais respostas.
6. Autor de uma pergunta com o maior número de visualizações.
7. Autor da maioria das perguntas.
8. Autor da maioria das respostas.

Entre todas as postagens que satisfazem cada condição, selecionamos apenas uma que tenha a pontuação mais alta ou a postagem mais antiga. O concurso será realizado em duas sessões.

- *Primeira sessão*: de 1 de janeiro a 10 de janeiro.
- *Segunda sessão*: de 11 de janeiro a 31 de janeiro.

Cada sessão terá seus vencedores, ao mesmo tempo em que concedemos um prêmio por pessoa. Assim, se você se tornar o melhor em uma categoria várias vezes ou o melhor em várias categorias em uma sessão, você receberá apenas um prêmio.

#### O prêmio

O prêmio mais significativo, claro, é o conhecimento, e vale a pena participar apenas por isso! Além do conhecimento e do bom humor, os vencedores receberão ótimos ganhos!

#### Vamos começar no dia 1º de janeiro!

Conhece alguém que pode fazer uma ótima pergunta na tag [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo)? Por favor, convide-os a participar! Conhece alguém que possa responder? Por favor, convide-os também!

Aguardamos suas perguntas e respostas na tag [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo). Por favor, não esqueça de se inscrever na tag, para não perder novas perguntas! Boa sorte!

**Importante**: Os resultados serão contados 10 dias após o término de uma sessão, para que as chances de obter votos sejam iguais.

---

#### Como vamos identificar os vencedores

Usaremos as seguintes consultas SQL em [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

1. Autor de uma pergunta com a maior pontuação.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
2. Autor de uma resposta com a maior pontuação.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
3. Autor de uma resposta à sua própria pergunta, se a resposta obtiver uma pontuação maior do que qualquer outra resposta à pergunta (essa consulta procura respostas pessoais).

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.OwnerUserId = parent.OwnerUserId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
4. Autor de uma resposta aceita com a maior pontuação.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, parent.Title, p.Score
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.Id = parent.AcceptedAnswerId AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.Score desc;
   ```
5. Autor de uma pergunta que recebe mais respostas.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.AnswerCount, p.Score  
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY p.AnswerCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
6. Autor de uma pergunta com o maior número de visualizações.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, m.ViewCount, p.Score 
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
     Join PostMetadata m on m.PostId = p.Id
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   ORDER BY m.ViewCount desc, p.Score desc;
   ```
7. Autor da maioria das perguntas.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT (DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```
8. Autor da maioria das respostas.

   ```
   SELECT p.OwnerUserId, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Id) AS Number
   From Posts p 
     Join Posts parent on parent.Id = p.ParentId 
     Join PostTags t on t.PostId = parent.Id 
   Where t.TagId = 128 AND p.PostTypeId = 2 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
   GROUP BY p.OwnerUserId
   ORDER BY Number desc;
   ```

Comment: Uma dúvida: a pergunta deve ser feita no Meta ou no site principal?

Comment: Hi @Sam! It should be a regular question with the tag on the main site.

Answer (score 10):

A lot of thanks to [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) for the translation!

---

## New Year Algorithm 2019 - resultados da primeira sessão

Vamos dar os parabéns aos vencedores da primeira sessão!

#### Autor da pergunta com a maior pontuação

[@Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/49033/marcus-nunes) com a pergunta “[Por que aprender algoritmos diferentes que resolvem o mesmo problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353853/17539)”, que teve 15 votos positivos e 1 resposta.

#### Autor da resposta com a maior pontuação

[@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) com [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353861/17539) à pergunta “[Por que aprender algoritmos diferentes que resolvem o mesmo problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353853/17539)”. A resposta teve 16 votos positivos!

#### Autor da resposta aceita com a maior pontuação

[@Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132/victor-stafusa) com [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354997/17539) à pergunta “[Algoritmo de ordenação, Stream Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354988/17539)”. A resposta teve 10 votos positivos.

#### Autor da pergunta que teve mais respostas e mais visualizações

[@Homer Simpson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/77665/homer-simpson) com a pergunta “[O que são algoritmos evolutivos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354123/17539)”, que teve 15 votos positivos e 3 respostas, que juntas tiveram 18 votos positivos, e 155 visualizações desde que foi perguntada.

#### Autor que fez mais perguntas

[@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) fez 4 perguntas com a *tag* [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo). No total, elas tiveram 30 votos positivos!

#### Autor que escreveu mais respostas

[@Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado) respondeu 2 perguntas, com 11 votos positivos no total.

---

Muito obrigado a todos que participaram! A segunda sessão do *New Year Algorithm 2019* está a todo vapor! Você ainda tem a chance de se tornar um dos vencedores. Basta escrever perguntas e respostas com a *tag* [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo)!

Answer (score 4):

A lot of thanks to [@Piovezan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/357/piovezan) for the translation!

---

### Resultado da segunda sessão do Algoritmo de Ano Novo 2019

Por favor junte-se às congratulações dos vencedores da segunda sessão!

#### Autor de uma pergunta com a maior pontuação, de uma pergunta que mais recebeu resposta, e de uma pergunta com o maior número de visualizações

[@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) com uma pergunta “[O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/17539)” que recebeu 21 votos positivos, 3 respostas, e 249 visualizações.

#### Autor de uma resposta com a maior pontuação

[@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) com [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356342/17539) para a pergunta “[O que faz a invalidação de cache ser uma solução difícil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356320/17539)”. A resposta obteve 15 votos positivos.

#### Autor de uma resposta aceita com maior pontuação

[@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) com [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356603/17539) para a pergunta “[Quando e como devo usar operador instanceof e typeof no JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356582/17539)”. A resposta recebeu 14 votos positivos.

#### Autor do maior número de perguntas

[@Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero) fez 4 perguntas que obtiveram 49 votos positivos e 6 respostas no total.

#### Autor do maior número de respostas

[@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) respondeu 2 perguntas. As respostas somaram 20 votos positivos no total.

---

Muito obrigado a todos que participaram! O Algoritmo de Ano Novo acabou, mas continuem fazendo e respondendo perguntas com [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo). Estou certo que essas perguntas decoram belamente a central de conhecimentos que provoca muitas emoções positivas na comunidade.

Comment: Hmm... Peguei segundo lugar na autoria do maior número de perguntas... o primeiro lugar é o Maniero, que já havia ganhado outras vezes... também quero meu swag. :D É de comer?