# Feliz ano novo 7E3!

Tags: suporte

A lot of thanks to [@ hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) for the translation!

---

Às vésperas do Ano Novo, vamos relembrar os momentos do ano que passou e pensar nos nossos planos para o ano que vem.

#### O que você lembra do ano que passou?

Cada um de nós pode ressaltar seus momentos mais importantes com relação à comunidade. Para mim, o ponto de virada foi a oportunidade de trabalhar com todos os sites internacionais, em particular com o seu (muito obrigado a todos por seu apoio e ajuda!). Começamos juntos com [nossa *tag* no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/international-sites), [adicionamos um manifesto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316522/274323), e começamos a compartilhar os [problemas, descobertas e iniciativas entre as comunidades internacionais](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323).

Tenho certeza que vocês também têm alguns momentos para compartilhar com a comunidade! *Por favor diga nas respostas a esta pergunta: o que você lembra sobre 2018?*

#### O ano em números

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | em Português       |  em Português     |
|                    | 2017               |  2018             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Perguntas         |     44 990         |    45 234         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Respostas         |     44 433         |    38 855         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Novos Usuários    |     34 814         |    32 417         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

A comunidade cresce a cada dia, assim como a base de conhecimento que criamos. No ano que passou, nós fizemos um trabalho fenomenal juntos, como podem ver acima. Muito obrigado a todos que fizeram parte disso.

#### Ano que vem teremos muito a fazer!

Gostaria de ressaltar alguns ponto importantes que podem ser cruciais no futuro próximo.

- *Mais pessoas significa mais ideias!* Seria ótimo ver todos que fizeram parte do Stack Overflow em Português ao longo dos anos, assim como os muitos usuários novos que certamente trarão um pouco de si: alguns irão compartilhar conhecimento sobre a interface de usuário, outros irão escrever com entusiasmo sobre *drivers*, e outros adicionarão novos processos à comunidade! Pessoas de verdade são a parte mais importante do Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, convide seus amigos para compartilhar conhecimento no site, perguntando e respondendo, e conte a eles nossa [missão](/help/manifesto). Eles tornarão a participação na comunidade ainda mais interessante.
- *Os problemas, descobertas e iniciativas atuais das comunidades internacionais no MSE*. Podemos aumentar de forma significativa nossa eficiência em [trocar ideias uns com os outros no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317116/274323). Além disso, nossos problemas em comum receberão mais atenção e soluções novas e interessantes. É muito provável que a colaboração acelere o ritmo de crescimento de cada comunidade internacional. É como dizem: "Duas cabeças pensam melhor que uma, principalmente se forem de culturas diferentes".
- *Nós mesmos criarmos a base de conhecimento*. Se ordenarmos todas as perguntas por número de visualizações, poderemos ver que em cada site internacional que no top-3 há pelo menos uma pergunta respondida pelo próprio autor (e isso também é verdade no Stack Overflow em Inglês). Geralmente perguntas que o próprio autor responde acrescentam informações importantes sobre algum aspecto técnico de maneira canônica. Estas perguntas possuem uma alta demanda entre nossos colegas. Seria ótimo no ano que vem ver mais perguntas interessantes assim, com as melhores práticas. Tenho certeza que elas atrairão muita atenção e *feedback* positivo.

Acredito que a oportunidade de influenciar a vida de milhares de pessoas com apenas uma resposta era, é e será o principal motivador e recompensa por participar do site. Seria ótimo se no ano que vem focássemos juntos nos pontos principais: nossa biblioteca de respostas detalhadas para cada pergunta de programação e nossa comunidade. Tenho certeza que a colaboração nesta biblioteca nos trará muitos sentimentos positivos.

**Feliz 7E3!**

[image]

Quase me esqueci! [O Ano Novo nunca vem sozinho...](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7516/17539)

Answer (score 4):

Houve um tempo em que se falavam em viagens espaciais regulares, carros parecidos com naves, robôs etc... tecnologias onde a figura do teclado, por exemplo, para os mais visionários, seria coisa do passado uns anos após o ano 2000... Me refiro principalmente aos anos 80, período em que passei da fase infantil para a adolescência (sou de 1974), e ouvia muito dessas coisas quando a tecnologia da informática estava dando seus primeiros passos mais significativos, digamos. Mas chegamos a 2019 e nada disso aconteceu de fato — chegamos a 2019 e os carros não voam e não se parecem com naves (embora alguns modelos se pareçam mesmo, mas não saem do chão rs) e o teclado ainda é indispensável.

Claro que a tecnologia hoje é avançadíssima, mas não chegou aos pés do que se previa e sonhava àquela época. No entanto, pelo menos não me lembro, naquela época não se falava em uma rede mundial como a internet é hoje. Para mim, o StackOverflow é algo fruto da tecnologia que alcançamos, no mais alto nível que ela pode oferecer hoje em dia.

O SO extrai o suprassumo do que a área de programação pode oferecer. É como se você selecionasse as melhores frutas e delas fizesse o melhor néctar.

Pra mim, o ano de 2018 foi crucial em relação ao SOpt, ou seja, ou eu abandonava o site ou ficaria de vez. Foi uma decisão difícil. Tive meus problemas, atritos, discórdias e tudo mais, mas aprendi muita coisa, principalmente na área de relacionamento em uma comunidade online. Aprendi coisas que eu não sabia ou não tinha noção. Conheci diferentes pontos de vista e comportamentos de colegas, que me fizeram pensar. Mas em tudo, eu só tenho a agradecer, porque o SOpt me ajudou não apenas na parte técnica e profissional, como também na parte pessoal, em como lidar com várias situações.

Sou relativamente novo no site, sempre buscando aprender mais, e espero que o SOpt dure ainda mais anos pela frente, e que se torne melhor a cada ano, e que seus usuários possam aproveitar o que ele tem melhor, e tem muito mais de melhor a oferecer, com certeza.

**Feliz 2019 a todos!**