# O que você quer aprender em 2019?  Moderators Award 2019 

Tags: debate

> [**Veja o resultado do sorteio aqui.**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7629/227)

---

A equipe de moderadores do Stack Overflow em Português inspirou-se no concurso ["Algoritmo de Ano Novo de 2019"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7516/new-year-algorithm-2019) (tradução livre :P) e também convida a comunidade a participar do...

## Prêmio da Moderação de 2019

#### Um prêmio único

Note que esta não é uma promoção comum. O prêmio está sendo oferecido pela [equipe voluntária de moderação do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) (isso mesmo... aqueles chatos que às vezes ficam em cima pedindo para melhorar as postagens).

Segundo as informações que recebemos do Stack Overflow, esta é a primeira vez que os próprios moderadores de um site premiam a comunidade, o que torna o nosso site ainda mais único do que nunca!

***Agradecemos por fazer parte dele!***

#### Requisitos para participar ✅

1. Responda esta pergunta dizendo o que você planeja aprender em 2019, *e que tenha alguma relação com linguagens de programação, algoritmos, ciências da computação, ou qualquer coisa a ver com nosso site*.
2. Ganhe pelo menos 50 pontos no mês de Janeiro com novas publicações, perguntando ou respondendo, no Stack Overflow em Português.

A resposta e os pontos serão contabilizados até à meia-noite de 31 de Janeiro, horário de Brasília. Apenas uma resposta por usuário será contabilizada.

#### Vencedores ‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️

**Três** respostas, cujos autores atendam aos critérios mínimos de pontuação, serão escolhidas por sorteio.

#### Prêmios

O ganhador que estiver no Brasil  receberá um vale-presente de  **R$100,00** da [Livraria Cultura](https://livrariacultura.com.br).

[image: Livros valem mais do que barras de ouro]

Se estiver em outro país, um prêmio equivalente será avaliado de acordo com as opções locais.

A partir daí é com você! Não vai ter desculpas para aproveitar 2019 para tornar-se um profissional ainda melhor!

Comment: Os 50 pontos devem ser ganhos no mês de janeiro, né? Acho que valeria clarificar isso...

Comment: @carla Feito. Deve estar mais claro agora.

Comment: Quero falar sobre duas coisas: não estou concorrendo aos prêmios, mesmo tendo feito algum esforço que possa parecer que eu esteja, este principalmente por razões óbvias. Eu posso participar do processo de escolha de quem receber (nem sei bem qual será o processo :) ), mas quero deixar claro que a premiação não é dada por mim. Não quero ter o crédito da generosidade de ter oferecido ele. E claro agradecer, acho que em nome da comunidade, pela generosidade.

Comment: @utluiz Pontos ganhos no mês de janeiro apenas com publicações neste mês ou vale pontos ganhos em publicações antigas?

Comment: @LINQ Excelente pergunta. Editei o post para esclarecer. Os pontos válidos são de novas publicações, já que a ideia é promover o engajamento.

Comment: Quando vai ser sorteado? @_@

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Vou ver se consigo publicar o resultado na segunda.

Comment: Ansioso! Já até dei uma namorada em alguns livros... Kkkk

Comment: Resultado do sorteio: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7629/227

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Segue o que pretendo aprender e os respectivos *mottos* para cada área de conhecimento:

**Ferramentas:** *Ir Além da JVM*.

Após mais de uma década trabalhando com `Java`, invariavelmente mergulhando em outras linguagens que rodam na JVM como `Scala`, `Groovy` e `Kotlin` meu objetivo esse ano é diversificar minha *stack* em ambiente profissional. Estou interessado em trabalhar com `Python` e `Node.js`, mesmo que isso signifique dar um "passo para trás" temporário em minha carreira. Eu tive uma breve experiência com Python em uma *startup* e adorei; infelizmente acabei saindo da empresa muito rapidamente e não deu tempo para absorver tudo o que aprendi. No meu tempo livre também estou brincando com Python para fins específicos. Já tenho inclusive um ambiente `Spark` montado (estive experimentando com sistemas distribuídos em Scala, agora devo focar em portar algumas das minhas aplicações *toy* para Python). Também tive uma excelente experiência desenvolvendo pequenos micro-serviços com .NET Core (no Linux, com o Visual Studio Code e o Rider), e, se conseguir, também gostaria de levar esses estudos em paralelo.

**Técnicas**: *Rever fundamentos e me tornar um programador melhor*.

Tive a sorte de ter mergulhado em *DevOps*, sistemas distribuídos e *Cloud Computing* já faz algum tempo ([Slides de uma Palestra minha sobre o assunto em 2013](https://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2013/09/slides-escalabilidade-web-devops-e-paas.html)). Isso me abriu excelentes oportunidades profissionais e iniciou um círculo virtuoso em que curiosidade e conhecimento ampliam oportunidades para experimentação e vice-versa (certamente recomendo esse caminho).

De forma mais rasa também molhei meus pés no mundo de *Data Engineering* e aprendi o que consegui sobre *Big Data*. Dentro das minhas limitações, aprendi até um pouco sobre *Data Science*.

Esse ano porém, razoavelmente liberto da necessidade de estudar "o assunto quente do momento", meu objetivo é voltar as raízes e trabalhar meu conhecimento de base. Em suma: Boas práticas de Desenvolvimento de Software, Design, Algoritmos, Redes e Arquitetura de Computadores.

Em especial, comprei o [Clean Architecture](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18043011-clean-architecture) (O último da série de livros *"Clean"* do Uncle Bob) e a segunda edição do [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) (que por decisão do Martin Fowler, usa JavaScript ao invés de Java). Também desenterrei a cópia de [Cracking The Coding Interview](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com/) que comprei em 2015. Para complementar, possuo acesso a uma biblioteca virtual com livros clássicos de computação. Está sendo divertido revisitar livros da época da faculdade (em versões atualizadas e em Inglês), já com maturidade para absorver melhor o que os autores estão tentando passar. Entre os destaques da categoria "Vale a pena ler de novo" estão: [Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Kurose-Computer-Networking-A-Top-Down-Approach-7th-Edition/PGM1101673.html), [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) e [Computer Organization and Architecture](http://williamstallings.com/ComputerOrganization/).

**Comportamento / processo / metodologias**: *Desenvolvimento "laboratorial": Experimentação -> POC -> MVP (ou morte!)*

*Agile* agora é razoavelmente *mainstream*; como alguém eternamente desgostoso com o estado das coisas, tenho que fazer ecoar a palavra de [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/agile-aus-2018.html), e, até certo ponto, dar o braço a torcer para o [Erik Meijer](https://vimeo.com/110554082). A coisa não está funcionando como deveria. O entusiasmo de programadores e os valores do *Agile*, ao meu ver, foram subvertidos pela indústria em mais um produto para *coaches* e evangelistas. Em especial, *Scrum* parece ter virado o refúgio de muito gente que não entendeu a *essência* do [Manifesto Ágil](https://agilemanifesto.org/). A culpa não é "deles", é nossa.

Após anos experimentando novas áreas, trocando ou acumulando funções de liderança técnica, gerência de projetos, arquitetura de soluções e arquitetura empresarial eu fiz as pazes comigo mesmo e com o [princípio de incompetência de Peter](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_de_Peter). Finalmente entendi quem sou e onde quero estar.

Dessa forma, volto a essência do modelo Jedi / Padawan (ou *Sith Master* e *Sith apprentice*; aqui não há discriminação de lado da força :D); algo que vale tanto para aprendizado quanto para execução.

Em 2019 eu  gostaria de trabalhar com [*RTD*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_and_development), busco uma oportunidade com foco em experimentação e desenvolvimento de protótipos. Funciono bem trabalhando em pequenas células razoavelmente autônomas. Gosto de exercer o papel de mentor para programadores menos experientes, sinto também muita falta de um mentor mais experiente acompanhando o meu progresso. Em especial, me faz falta a presença de alguém que me ajude a explorar boas ideias e, por outro lado, saiba trabalhar meu entusiasmo quando for hora de parar de investir ou até mesmo jogar fora ideias que levarão a um beco sem saída.

---

Resumindo os pontos acima: Vejo 2019 como um ano para "reaprender" ferramentas e técnicas de base. Mais do que isso, é um ano para reaprender o que eu acho que sei, incluindo o que acho que sou e a forma como acho que devo aprender.

[image: That's so Meta]

Comment: By the way, @utluiz, estava preparando esse texto para postar em outra mídia. Porém, fiquei tão feliz em ver sua iniciativa que resolvi postar por aqui para dar uma força. Se você achar que o formato não está muito adequado me deixe saber.

Comment: Grande post, e não estou falando do comprimento :) As pessoas deveriam prestar bastante atenção para ele.

Comment: Excelente publicação. Eu também «sinto também muita falta de um mentor mais experiente acompanhando o meu progresso», já tive um durante os primeiros anos de trabalho e foi quando consegui aprender mais e melhor.

Comment: @Jorge B., pois é, um grande mentor faz toda a diferença em qualquer área (é por isso que músicos, mesmo grandes virtuosos, costumam fazer "aulas", ao menos semanalmente com um professor que eles respeitem). Ano passo tentei um desses programas de mentoring voluntário mas não foi bem o que eu esperava. Esse ano, se acabar pulando de galho novamente, pretendo valorizar oportunidades de aprendizado e mentoring mais do que salário ou título. Acho que essa ideia casa bem com a outra de trabalhar com linguagens com as quais estou menos familiarizado.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Excelente post e muito detalhado! Um engajamento assim faz tudo valer  ainda mais a pena! :D

Answer (score 25):

Vou finalmente fazer aquele mestrado em computação que venho adiando faz 3 anos.

[image: gato sem mexendo no computador com legenda I have no idea what I'm doing]

Comment: O gato é o melhor! A propósito, também to enrolando um mestrado, só que ainda não ganhei a disposição para ir atrás dele, hahaha

Answer (score 23):

## Desktop

Quando eu era um filhote sempre desenvolvia apps voltados para Desktop.

[image: cat computer]

## Backend

Depois que eu cresci, passei a me aventurar no mundo Web só que focado em desenvolvimento Backend, mas sem me aprofundar muito em HTML, CSS e Javascript.

[image: cat foco]

## O que vou aprender em 2019

Agora neste ano, vou me focar mais em **HTML**, **CSS** e **Javascript** e também irei me aprofundar nos princípios do protocolo **HTTP** que é de extrema importância para quem quer ir para este ramo. Então, muitas perguntas nessas tags iram surgi ;D!

E com este dinheiro vou comprar livros relacionados as essas tecnologias que pretendo aprender.

[image: cat money]

E vamos lá :D

[image: cat code]

Comment: A Carla usou uma foto de gato e tem a maior pontuação, e então você chega com o nickname de gato, com uma foto de gato e ainda por cima faz uma pergunta com 4 fotos de gatos, sua pontuação vai subir igual um foguete (Isso é desleal rsrs)

Comment: Fui obrigado a da +1

Comment: @WictorChaves Purrr Purrr!

Comment: Chegar no 10K que é bom, nada? :P

Answer (score 19):

Quero focar mais nos estudos em `JavaScript` para poder aprender a trabalhar com `GSAP/TweenMax` e criar formar mais dinâmicas de interagir com `SVGs` e `animações CSS`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilizo muito em AS3, é uma ótima biblioteca de animação :)

Comment: @bio AS3 ainda existe? xD. Brincadeiras a parte tb já trabalhei um pouco com Flash. Mas ainda bem que o SVG vai para preencher algumas lacunas que ele deixou!

Comment: ainda existe, mas não faço mais serviços pra web, só pra digital signage. E sim, ainda bem que surgiu o html5, bora lá! \o/

Answer (score 18):

Em 2019... quero acessar **o lado negro da lua**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Brincadeiras a parte, o efeito óptico apresentado na capa do álbum representa muito bem meu objetivo este ano: **refração**. Vejo e, principalmente, admiro muito a capacidade que alguns usuários do Stack Overflow possuem de distribuir conhecimento, seja fazendo perguntas pertinentes à comunidade, seja elaborando excelentes respostas.

Utilizo o Stack Overflow basicamente porque ele une com maestria três das coisas que mais gosto:

1. Aprender;
2. Ensinar;
3. Python;

Neste ano - mas não limitado a ele - pretendo aprimorar minhas habilidades em ensinar, de modo que eu possa ainda mais colaborar não só com a comunidade do site, mas com a comunidade de programação por completa. Acredito que tenho potencial para colaborar com muito mais do que faço atualmente e pretendo explorar esse potencial. Aprimorar o processo de converter (ensinando) algo que parece complexo de forma simples.

O efeito de refração apresentado pelo prisma basicamente *transforma* a luz branca, complexa e concentrada, espalhada por todo o espectro de frequência, em feixes espalhados espacialmente cuja faixa espectral é bem mais curta. Trabalhar com uma faixa de frequência menor é mais fácil que quando considerado todo o espectro. O mesmo efeito físico pode ser aplicado à programação. Muitas vezes a forma como certo assunto é abordado já funciona como prisma, deixando aquilo que inicialmente era enigmático e complexo em algo simples e compreensível. Com certeza você já passou por alguma resposta assim aqui no site.

A capacidade de refração de um prisma depende diretamente do material que é feito, assim como a capacidade de transmitir conhecimento depende diretamente do conhecimento que cada um possui. Assim, para aprimorar minha capacidade em ensinar, terei que estudar muitas vezes mais. Um investimento de R$ 100,00 em livros será de grande ajuda :D

Comment: Já que vai de Lua pode começar por aqui: https://www.lua.org/ :P

Answer (score 17):

Meu plano para 2019 é aprender *computação gráfica*, usando preferencialmente o [`Vulkan`](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/).

Eu sempre pensei em fazer alguns jogos do estilo *Tycoon* (como RollerCoaster Tycoon, Sid Meiers Railroads!, Locomotion, OpenTTD, Rise of Industries...). Infelizmente, esse tipo de jogo morreu, não há bons jogos sendo lançados e cada vez tenho mais vontade de criar um.

Entretanto, eu não faço a menor ideia de como desenhar um pixel na tela. O meu maior problema sempre foi não me adaptar em nenhuma engine existente no mercado (como Unity, Unreal Engine, Godot...), nunca tive paciência para aprender a usa-la.

Para mim passou a se tornar estranho. Eu sei programar (bem, ou mal), mas eu não programar um código que para mostrar um mero quadrado no meio do monitor. Meu objetivo em 2019 se tornou justamente entender como as imagens são mostradas e como são criadas, e talvez, criar um jogo de gerenciamento.

---

*Se eu lembrar, voltarei aqui no final de 2019 para dizer se realmente conseguir aprender isso ou não.*

Comment: Tb adoro esses jogos e sempre quis fazer algo na linha, mas vai ficar na vontade mesmo :)

Comment: Cities XXL é o primeiro mais ou menos recente que me vem à cabeça, se bem que nunca o joguei, apenas joguei o primeiro Cities XL. Mas concordo plenamente que o tipo quase morreu, e ha muito tempo atrás era um estilo muito forte no mercado. Em relação à aprendizagem acho que compensa sempre bem mais aprender a fazer do zero, antes de utilizar um engine, para a pessoa ter uma mínima noção do que está por trás.

Comment: Eu também curto esse tipo de jogo, estava até vendo o [openRCT2](https://github.com/OpenRCT2/OpenRCT2) esses dias.

Comment: Sugiro uma espiada em http://godotengine.org

Comment: @Renan Por falar em opens um que eu joguei não há muito tempo e que meu deu grande nostalgia foi o [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/en/). Na altura quando saiu, o original claro chamado Transport Tycoon, foi um sucesso e um dos primeiros do gênero.

Answer (score 16):

Eu gostaria de aprender a trabalhar com machine learning em [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Assim, eu compararia os resultados de python com [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) (que já conheço muito bem) e verificaria se, para as minhas necessidades, faz diferença mudar a linguagem que utilizo.

Comment: recomendo um canal no youtube: canal sandeco

Answer (score 15):

Comecei minha carreira como desenvolvedor recentemente, trabalhei muito tempo com suporte e surgiu uma oportunidade para trabalhar como desenvolvedor, a principio fiquei receoso mas abracei este desafio e hoje estou trabalhando com `C#`.

E esta foi a melhor decisão que fiz na minha vida! Definitivamente eu encontrei a área de atuação para a minha vida, hoje estou aprendendo `C#` ( já que estou trabalhando com isso), mas estou me aprofundando no `Angular`, já que o mercado está quente e eu não quero mais parar de programar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 14):

Comecei minha carreira a 1 ano atrás trabalhando com Java ( JSF, JPA, PrimeFaces ... ), atualmente minha empresa possui um sistema legado e monolítico bem grande. Foi proposto quebrar esse sistema em microservices porém o custo/complexidade ficou inviável.

Gostei bastante desta arquitetura e em 2019 pretendo me aprofundar na stack Spring, microservices, DevOps. Quero seguir esta trilha !

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 14):

Quero aprender mais sobre .Net Core, EF Core, Angular, Node.js. e Docker.

Answer (score 14):

Pretendo aprender Ada (fiquei fascinado pelo o que é possível fazer com esse linguagem
na area de sistemas de defesa)e aprofundar meus conhecimentos em C++

Comment: sistemas de defesa da área de segurança da informação?

Answer (score 14):

Comecei um estágio em desenvolvimento com .Net, pretendo entender a fundo como o MVC funciona e como as coisas se relacionam (parece bem confuso até agora), e assim aprender mais C# e Javascript, além de outras coisas como Ajax, AngularJS, NodeJS. 
Também quero aprender mais banco de dados na prática, vi na faculdade mas ainda não sei usar muito bem.

Answer (score 13):

Gostaria de me dominar profissionalmente C++ voltado para área de engenharia de software e ciência da computação

Answer (score 13):

As minhas ultimas experiencias profissionais foram com `php`, agora estou trabalhando com `C#`, como trabalho principalmente com web, como consequência adquirir algumas experiencias com `Html`, `Css` e `Javascript`.

Estou aprendendo `Angular` e aproveitando o embalo fazendo algumas coisinhas utilizando `Ionic`.

E em paralelo a isso tudo, estou fazendo a minha pós-graduação.

Mas o que eu vou aprender este ano é `Django`! Comecei a programar utilizando `Python` e me apaixonei pela linguagem, como trabalho a mais tempo com web, acredito que este é o caminho ao qual eu devo seguir, queria aproveitar este ano para aprender mais sobre `Django`, já fiz alguns projetos e comprei alguns cursos na Udemy.

Minha intensão era começar no final de 2018, porem troquei de emprego, e tive que aprender o mais rápido possível sobre `C#` e `Angular`, mas em 2019 vou continuar minha caminhada para aprender `Django`!

Answer (score 12):

Pretendo me aprofundar em C++ e aprender [Aprendizado por reforço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).

Answer (score 12):

Quero mergulhar de cabeça nos conceitos da cultura **DevOps** de forma que possa aplicar na empresa que tô atualmente, além de reforçar a base (Sistemas Operacionais e Algoritmos) e só depois disso partir para as ferramentas.

Em linguagens quero aprofundar **Python** e **Golang** e ferramentas quero aprofundar *Jenkins*, *Docker(principalmente reforçar docker-compose)*, *Ansible*, *K8s* e a *stack* de monitoramento **ELK**.

E não menos importante, quero contribuir com mais qualidade no SOpt (e outras comunidades) com esse conhecimento novo que for adquirindo :D

Comment: Eu fugiria do mordomo, procuraria outra saída de CI, como o gitlab ou o travis...

Comment: Então.. já uso o Travis pra alguns projetos abertos (curti bastante a simplicidade inclusive), e o gitlab CI usei pouca coisa no community, com os runners compartilhados, não tive bons resultados, então acabei optando pelo mordomo, por ele ser 'orientado a plugin' tem facilitado muito minha vida :D

Answer (score 12):

Este ano fiquei bem focado em linguagens como [lua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua), [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) e [nodejs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs). Em 2019 planejo aprender e me aprofundar em muitas coisas, como [docker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker), [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react), [rust](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) e [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Planejo também contribuir mais em códigos abertos no github e começar novos projetos open source.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse meme ficou excelente :D

Answer (score 11):

Gostaria muuuuito de aprender mais sobre .Net Core, DevOps e Docker!

Answer (score 11):

Muitas vezes entro na listagem de perguntas da comunidade relacionadas a linguagem que eu "domino", vejo que cada vez sei menos ainda, todo dia aprendendo algo novo.

Eu planejo aprender mais e me especializar em `.NET` pra conseguir ajudar de fato as pessoas da comunidade como elas me ajudam e alavancar minha carreira.

Answer (score 11):

Quero aprofundar na linguagem **Python** para programar em *Rapberry/Arduino* mesclando com a vontade louca de entender mais sobre eletrônica. Quem sabe de vez em quando voltar a ler/estudar **Javascript** por puro prazer de aprender novas linguagens.

Pretendo reforçar a ideia de que "*só sei que nada sei*" e sempre aprender, gostei muito de participar deste site que é referência em termos de conhecimento ensinado.

Answer (score 11):

Quero aprender a programar jogos, vou tentar me dedicar esse ano a aprender.

Comment: pesquisa sobre game maker e unity ;)

Comment: eu iria de unrealEngine para o 3d e gameMaker2 para o 2d

Answer (score 11):

Em 2019 pretendo aprofundar mais meus estudos em `Javascript`, com um foco maior em `angular` e `react`, pretendo ajudar bastante as duvidas do site que estão dentro do meu conhecimento, mesmo ainda que não tenho nem 1 ano de casa na área de programação, pretendo ajudar a todos que eu conseguir, espero que meus esforços esse ano me deixem mais perto de conseguir o titulo de `MVP` que é uma de minhas metas de carreira, pretendo fazer minha primeira viagem para fora do Brasil, aprender inglês para aprimorar e facilitar meus estudos como programador. Espero acima de tudo que meus planos deem certo e vou fazer de tudo para que isso se concretize é isso, no final tudo da certo :) .

Answer (score 10):

Estou pensando seriamente em entrar de cabeça na linguagem *JavaScript* voltada a *Node.JS*, *React.JS* e *React-native*.

*JavaScript* tem sido tendência!

Answer (score 10):

Já passou por aquela fase em que olhou para si mesmo e pensou: "e aí, o que eu realmente sei?" pois é, trabalhei por um ano e meio desenvolvendo em c# numa empresa que não era de TI, com uns caras que não eram exatamente programadores e sendo olhando pelos gerentes sempre como parte do centro de custo da empresa, que não merece investimento, fazendo basicamente as mesmas coisas todos os dias, até que percebi que eu estava decretando a minha morte profissional se continuasse daquele jeito. Procurei um emprego novo, descobri que a vida não é apenas fazer crud, que há uma infinidade de possibilidades e linguagens que podem conversar entre si. No final de 2018, já no novo emprego, comecei a trabalhar também com React, e em 2019 pretendo me aprofundar nessa biblioteca, assim como pretendo aprender Angular e Node, além de outras "peças" do .NET framework como SignalR, etc.
Bom, por hora é isso, e vamos lá.

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu um emprego melhor, sucesso nessa nova jornada :)

Comment: @Leila Obrigado :)

Answer (score 10):

Em 2018 estudei Python e OpenCV, mas ainda da para aprender muita coisa. Então pretendo aperfeiçoar na linguagem Python e aprender novos algoritmos do OpenCV.

Este ano iniciei estudando PCL (Point Cloud Library) em conjunto com um sensor LiDAR 2D e pretendo iniciar os estudos de Inteligência Artificial da Udacity.

Answer (score 9):

Atualmente estou trabalhando com desenvolvimento web, tenho uma curso técnico no qual aprendi bastante coisa sobre `PHP, HTML, CSS`. Mas infelizmente o curso não focou muito em **JavaScript**, por isso quero aprender mais sobre a linguagem, consigo me virar com o pouco que já sei mas toda vez que eu preciso usar eu passo um sufoco rsrs.

Answer (score 9):

**Meus objetivos para 2019**

- Design Patterns: MVC, MVP e MVVM
- Desenvolvimento Mobile
- Desenvolvimento WEB
- Python

Sobre os conceitos envolvidos nestes assuntos até entendo *merreca*, mas nunca coloquei em prática.

Answer (score 8):

Em 2019 espero adquirir razoável fluência em Python e também aprender C e C++.

Answer (score 8):

## Meta de aprendizado para 2019

[image]

[Fonte da imagem](https://www.lynda.com/LinkedIn-tutorials/Setting-learning-goal/503811/588528-4.html)

Acho interessante delimitar algumas metas de aprendizado para 2019, esse desafio é bem pertinente já que vai ao encontro dos meus objetivos profissionais para esse ano de além de dominar alguma nova tecnologia de desenvolvimento é o da possibilidade de ingressar na minha primeira vaga de emprego como desenvolvedor.

### O que aprendi até agora

Olá para todos, eu me chamo Antônio, tenho 30 anos e sou recém formado em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas, vim de uma vida cheia de altos e baixos e não sou um desenvolvedor nato com muitos que já iniciam logo na adolescência e tenho pouco mais de 5 anos de prática com programação.

Como ainda não desenvolvi nada profissionalmente e possuo somente a experiência do meu projeto experimental de graduação,  senti a necessidade de conhecer novas tecnologias com as quais eu fosse mais afim e que me trouxessem possibilidades mais versáteis de como desenvolver soluções para possíveis novos empregos e clientes.

Ano passado da segunda metade do ano até agora eu foquei um pouco mais em adquirir intimidade com o Linux e usei um pouco do `Antergos`, `Ubuntu`, `Kubuntu` e `Manjaro Linux` e como configurar um ambiente de desenvolvimento nesses Sistemas operacionais afinal nem sempre eu poderei escolher com qual sistema operacional eu irei trabalhar em uma empresa e por isso eu dei certa atenção ao linux.

### O que vou aprender esse ano

Já esse ano de 2019 meu foco está mais front-end, quero desenvolver mais minhas habilidades de web design e viver algo mais criativo e por isso escolhi o `React Js` como foco de estudos. Eu já tenho certa intimidade com GIMP e Inkscape e por isso eu faço todo o *wireframe* das minhas interfaces sem grandes dificuldades e o que me falta mesmo é modelar tudo em `React`.

As tecnologias que eu pretendo masterizar junto ao React são o `Apollo GraphQL`, o `styled-components` e o `Mongo DB`, então pode se dizer que esse ano eu vou usar muito HTML, CSS e JS e desenvolver algo bonito, rápido e de preferência algo que vá além de somente uma interface bela, eu quer que seja útil.

Como eu estudei muito de blockchain, a cereja do bolo na minha aplicação será tudo em um banco descentralizado hosteado em um *blockchain* da `Steem`, sendo alimentado por uma `API GraphQL` para postar em um blog em um domínio gratuito, com custo zero e acessível para qualquer um que quiser um blog sem gastar nenhum dinheiro e com a garantia de que seus dados estão seguros em um blockchain que possui segurança impenetrável.

2019 é um ano de me desenvolver com o que tem de melhor no mercado e por isso que escolhi `React`, eu gosto muito desse espírito de *Hype* da tecnologia que é muito bom para gerar comunidade, documentação e o principal que é o *network* que eu tanto desejo construir.

Além das tecnologias acima citadas espero melhorar meu *`speaking`* em inglês que ainda é meio travado.

Um forte abraço a todos e espero que consigam aprender tudo que estão planejando nesse ano cheio de otimismo e novos projetos.

Answer (score 7):

Trabalhei como técnico em informática, mas o meu real desejo era trabalhar com desenvolvimento, comecei por conta própria com `Visual Basic` e logo consegui um estágio para trabalhar com Java, em uma oportunidade trabalhei como `DBA`, aprendi bastante sobre `Sql Server` e hoje trabalho com `C#`, quero continuar me aprofundar no `C#`, mas também quero aprender Angular e para isso estou buscando aprender `Javascript`.

Então caso eu ganhe vou investir todo o dinheiro em livros sobre `Javascript` e `Angular`, já que `C#` eu já estou evoluindo onde trabalho.

Answer (score 6):

- Vou estudar muito `Ruby on Rails` e `Python` para começar alguns projetos com aprendizado de maquina e futuramente criar um algoritmo para dominar o mundo (brincadeira, só para criar maquinas inteligentes mesmo).
- Estudar a tecnologia por trás dos robôs que fazem trade, pois pretendo aplica-lo ao meu futuro curso de Ciência da Computação.
- Conseguir ingressar no curso de Ciências da Computação na Universidade Federal de São Paulo (famosa USP).
- Bater a marca de 10 mil pontos de reputação no SOPT.

Answer (score 6):

Meu plano para 2019, finalmente parar de procrastinar, e dar continuidade a um objetivo pessoal, o qual é criar uma ferramenta de EAD focado em personalização de questionários.

Quero que as pessoas consigam se ajudar a estudar, e que consigam ter alguma ferramenta para que possa ver aonde está tendo dificuldade e pontualmente estudar essa deficiência, o projeto ainda esta bem cru, mas esse ano ele vai começar a tomar forma.(de novo)

E para isso eu estou estudando [**`Vue`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js), [**`Laravel`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) e [**`Machine Learning`**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning)

Abaixo deixo a logo do meu pequeno sonho!

Obrigado a todos!

E bons estudos!

[image: QiEstudo]

Comment: Muito Bom amigo!!! Seu projeto/sonho é importantíssimo, e qualquer coisa estaremos por aqui pelo sopt!!

Answer (score 6):

Nesse ano minha lista ta um pouco estranha:

1. Aprender Python que venho enrolando desde 2017;
2. Aprender Vue e Angular(v2), e dar aquele reforco no node.js;
3. Voltar como meus projetos em sistemas embarcados, principalmente com PIC e Atmel para ser mas exato;
4. Tentar fazer um mestrado onde eu moro atualmente(Turquia);
5. E por ultimo voltar aos estudos do Erlang.

Comment: Olá! Parabéns por ter vencido. Só queria avisar que enviamos um e-mail referente ao seu prêmio para sua conta do `@hotmail.com` que está cadastrado em seu perfil. Se quiser utilizar outro e-mail, por favor avise a moderação através de uma flag neste comentário.

Answer (score 5):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero simplesmente evoluir como programador, me apurar mais nos conceitos da programação.

Answer (score 5):

Em 2019, tenho como foco estudar principalmente javascript (Nodejs, Angular e Reactjs) e aprofundar ainda mais os conhecimentos em python e React Native.

Answer (score 5):

Depois de muito tempo sem trabalhar na área, estou voltando ao estudos, já estou aprendendo python e quero muito aprender JS.

Answer (score 5):

2019 será dedicado a linguagem Python! 
Devido a alguns problemas de saúde, fiquei um pouco distante dos estudos em 2018. Agora que estou melhor, quero criar meu próprio programa de gerenciamento. Como sou novato na linguagem, acho que minhas dúvidas colocadas aqui, serão quadruplicadas. rsrsrs...
Aproveito para agradecer desde já, aos usuários e ao Stack Overflow, pelo ótimo trabalho que fazem em distribuir o conhecimento.

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 5):

Em 2019 eu pretendo aprender Python o máximo que puder e partir para I.A. e Data Science.
Me interesso muito e fiquei louco pelo assunto.

Answer (score 5):

Esse ano quero me aprofundar no paradigma funcional e pensar em outras formas de desenvolver!

Além disso, queria aprender um pouco de ops, com foco na cultura DevOps, automatizando e pensando em formas de testar.

Answer (score 5):

Esse ano de 2019 quero começar a me aprofundar no backend, fazer as parada funcionar pra valer! ahahahah A dúvida é se eu começo com uma linguagem como c# (que seria útil para meu trabalho e faculdade) ou se meto as caras no node.js que to louco para estudar, pelo fato de ter uma noção de javascript...

Mas de qualquer forma este ano vai ser de muito estudo!

Answer (score 5):

Para este ano de 2019 planejo me dedicar mais em minha atuação como programador para WEB (atualmente em PHP/Javascript). E Aprender ainda mais sobre o Vue.js, finalizando o desenvolvimento de um jogo parado a mais de um ano em Vue.js que iniciei para testar e aprender mais rápido.

Desenvolver jogos sempre foi um sonho porém nunca prioridade devido a necessidades financeiras. Se assim for possivel, também pretendo continuar meus estudos da Unity também.

Answer (score 5):

Esse ano vou aprender Java para que eu posso ser valorizado na minha profissão. Minha região é muito focada em Java o que me impossibilita de focar em outras áreas.

Answer (score 4):

Em 2019 quero publicar meu primeiro App feito em React Native, mas para isso acontecer, preciso primeiro me dedicar no JS.

Comment: Que legal, vai ser somente no Rio Grande do Norte??

Comment: Acho que aqui não é um lugar para brincadeiras....

Comment: Esse é um tipo de tópico que as brincadeiras são bem mais aceitas, o meu comentário foi em tom de brincadeira ;]

Answer (score 4):

Estudar sobre os fundamentos de tudo que tenho interesse, programação em geral, JS, Windows, desenvolvimento web e também lógica e algoritmos.

Answer (score 4):

Meu objetivo em 2019 é aprender o `"ERRE"` mais acertando do que errando.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Para este ano de 2019 quero me aprofundar em Big Data, Análise de dados e **talvez** me tornar o *tal* **Cientista de Dados**!

PS: Se eu me lembrar e eu realmente me tornar um Cientista de Dados podem acreditar que eu vou voltar e substituir a foto abaixo por uma semelhante porém **REAL** rsrs..

[image: Cientista de Dados]

Answer (score 3):

2019 será para mim eu ano de aprendizagem:

1. Curso de Data Science;
2. Curso de React JS;
3. Curso de NodeJS;
4. Curso de React Native;
5. Aprender a programar. Afinal, nunca se para de aprender a programar.

Já comprei o de **Data Science.**

Answer (score 3):

Tenho 16 anos e atualmente só estudo.
Vi um pouco de Java em 2014 mas ganhei um pc decente em seguida e até o começo desse ano só joguei(não me arrependo, conheci muita gente usahdaus dei).
Decidi voltar a aprender programação e atualmente to focando em **HTML/CSS** pra ir pra **JS** e depois **PHP**(até o momento to com isso em mente mas tudo pode mudar).