#  Parabéns aos ganhadores do Moderators Award 2019 

Tags: debate

### Agradecimento aos participantes

Antes de mais nada, uma  salva de palmas  aos **26** participantes que atenderam aos requisitos do sorteio:

- [8biT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/116567/8bit)
- [Albertt Santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132363/albertt-santos)
- [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss)
- [Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly)
- [Bulfaitelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59502/bulfaitelo)
- [Cadu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/134515/cadu)
- [carla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13626/carla)
- [Daniel Falbel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6036/daniel-falbel)
- [danieltakeshi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/75104/danieltakeshi)
- [Diego Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23919/diego-souza)
- [Francisco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/62269/francisco)
- [gato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/27190/gato)
- [George Wurthmann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/35358/george-wurthmann)
- [HudsonPH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/48274/hudsonph)
- [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl)
- [Inkeliz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/inkeliz)
- [Izak Mandrak](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/136946/izak-mandrak)
- [LipESprY -de folga-](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45810/lipespry-de-folga)
- [Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/49033/marcus-nunes)
- [OtavioCapel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/99859/otaviocapel)
- [Rennan Moura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/135691/rennan-moura)
- [Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam)
- [sant0will](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/110833/sant0will)
- [utm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/135641/utm)
- [Victor Laio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/61775/victor-laio)
- [Wictor Chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74441/wictor-chaves)

### Metodologia

Primeiro, lembremos dos requisitos:

- Ganhar 50 pontos com novas postagens em Janeiro
- Responder ao [post original](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7524/227)

Após a validação dos usuários, com a lista acima em mãos, foi realizado um
 sorteio  com os participantes através de um site que escolhe aleatoriamente um número de ganhadores dentro uma lista, no caso, as URLs dos perfis.

### [Resultado do sorteio](https://sorteador.com.br/embaralhador/resultado/95077)

> - [Albertt Santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/132363/albertt-santos)
> - [Izak Mandrak](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/136946/izak-mandrak)
> - [HudsonPH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/48274/hudsonph)

### Curiosidades

Eu analisei pessoalmente (por duas vezes, para garantir) as respostas ao post do prêmio e os pontos de cada usuário em Janeiro, obtendo então a lista acima com 26 usuários que atenderam aos requisitos. Decidi por esta abordagem ao invés de uma query para que eu pudesse sentir como foi a participação geral no período.

Foi interessante notar como muitos usuários se engajaram mais e se esforçaram para participar durante o período. Também considero positivo o fato de que os ganhadores são usuários relativamente novos em sem pontuação expressiva, o que, espero, seja um incentivo para quem está começando.

Outra fato interessante é que alguns usuários conseguiram todos os pontos necessários com uma única boa reposta que foi aceita (15 pontos) e que recebeu alguns votos a favor (10 pontos cada). Outros usuários, que talvez ainda não se sintam tão confortáveis para responder muito, fizeram boas perguntas e obtiveram votos a favor (5 pontos cada) contribuindo assim com uma boa discussão e troca de conhecimento.

Infelizmente, alguns usuários ganharam pontos, mas não os 50 necessários no período especificado, então tive que excluí-los do sorteio. Eu realmente gostaria de ter incluído todos, mas *regras são regras* e seria injusto com os que se esforçaram para chegar lá.

### Próximos passos

Os ganhadores devem aguardar e reponder a um e-mail que a moderação vai enviar em breve.

Comment: Parabéns aos ganhadores e obrigado moderação pela iniciativa <3! Espero ver mais sorteios assim no futuro :P

Comment: Sacanagem, heim! Já estava preparando a lista de compras na livraria pra gastar esses R$ 100... T.T

Comment: Parabéns a todos que participaram e se esforçaram, vou até dar uma dica que acho que seria legal para a próxima edição.... Acho que poder optar por cursos on-line tb seria um um prêmio legal ;) []´s

Comment: Opa! Obrigado! Iniciativa incrível! Parabéns ao moderadores! =D

Comment: Parabéns a todos, e obrigado pela oportunidade de participar do sorteio, valeuuu!!!

Comment: Parabéns, agora não tem mais desculpas para estudar. u.u

Comment: Parabens a todos que participaram :)

Comment: utluiz "ganhadores" usa-se no Brasil em vez de vencedores?

Comment: @JorgeB. Provavelmente não estou sendo preciso, mas em geral vejo "ganhador" e "vencedor" usados como sinônimos no Brasil. [Exemplo](https://g1.globo.com/mundo/noticia/2018/12/25/o-misterio-do-ganhador-de-us-15-bi-na-loteria-dos-eua-que-ainda-nao-foi-buscar-o-premio.ghtml)

Comment: Um parabéns atrasado. Foi uma excelente iniciativa!

Comment: @HudsonPH *teşekkür ederiz* por participar. (e foi tudo que consegui aprender de Turco)

Comment: @utluiz obrigado!! já esta falando mais turco do que eu :P

Answer (score 12):

Parabéns aos vencedores e também a quem participou :)

Answer (score 9):

Antes de mais nada gostaria de agradecer a todos que participaram do sorteio e a essa iniciativa tomada pelo site, vocês incentivam e ajudam a comunidade brasileira de programação de uma maneira absurda, vocês são fodas!!!

Venho por meio dessa resposta também, ressaltar que recebi o prêmio e estou muito feliz com minha nova [aquisição](https://www.livrariacultura.com.br/p/livros/informatica-e-tecnologia/software/codigo-limpo-2874223), agora é estudar bastante e seguir em frente aprendendo cada dia mais, obrigado mais uma vez por contribuírem com meu aprendizado e crescimento profissional.

Sintam-se a vontade em me dar dicas de livros ou matérias para leitura, valeu galera!!!

Answer (score 9):

Gostaria de deixar aqui os meus mais sinceros agradecimentos pelo apoio e incentivo da comunidade Stack Overflow.

Confesso que eu não tinha grandes pretensões no sorteio, quando recebi com surpresa o e-mail do [@utluiz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), imaginei que se tratava de SPAM ou algum tipo de "e-mail-fraude" e quase que meu Vale Presente foi parar na lixeira.

Como sou atuante da área de Matemática/Estatística minha escolha foi [Os Segredos Matemáticos dos Simpsons](https://www.livrariacultura.com.br/p/livros/ciencias-exatas/matematica/os-segredos-matematicos-dos-simpsons-46129353), para quem acha a Matemática chata, esse é um ótimo livro para mudar de ideia.

> As pessoas inventam estatísticas para provar qualquer coisa. 40% das
>   pessoas sabem disso.
>
> Homer Simpson

Também aceito sugestões de livros galera!

Answer (score 8):

Parabéns a todos que participaram e ao site!

Essa iniciativa não é apenas um estímulo mas também uma forma de prestigiar e valorizar os usuários.

Fiquei contente em ver meu nome na lista, mesmo que eu não tenha ganhado os  . Tomara que tenha mais concursos desses .

Answer (score 8):

Agradecendo novamente pela a iniciativa e pelo premio recebido,

Ahh mas você mora na turquia, como vc recebeu o premio? 
Ganhei um vale presente em uma loja de livros da turquia. :)

Por enquanto só tenho esse livro em mente [Angular Design Patterns](https://www.idefix.com/ekitap/angular-design-patterns) mas quero pegar outro livro ou ebook.